# How to truncate long matching lines returned by grep or ack

Tags: grep, unix, ack

I want to run ack or grep on HTML files that often have very long lines. I don't want to see very long lines that wrap repeatedly. But I do want to see just that portion of a long line that surrounds a string that matches the regular expression. How can I get this using any combination of Unix tools?

Comment: What's `ack`?  Is it a command you use when you don't like something? Something like `ack file_with_long_lines | grep pattern`? :-)

Comment: @Alok `ack` (known as `ack-grep` on Debian) is `grep` on steroids.  It also has the `--thpppt` option (not kidding).  http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: While the `--thpppt` feature is somewhat controversial, the key advantage appears to be that you can use Perl regexes directly, not some crazy `[[:space:]]` and characters like `{`, `[`, etc. changing meaning with the `-e` and `-E` switches in a way that's impossible to remember.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163726 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8101701

Comment: I use `grep --color=always | less -S -R`. Then, type `-R` to unfold/fold the lines.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You could use the grep options `-oE`, possibly in combination with changing your pattern to `".{0,10}<original pattern>.{0,10}"` in order to see some context around it:

```
       -o, --only-matching
              Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.

       -E, --extended-regexp
             Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e., force grep to behave as egrep).
```

For example (from @Renaud's comment):

```
grep -oE ".{0,10}mysearchstring.{0,10}" myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, you could try `-c`:

```
       -c, --count
              Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
              for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
              below), count non-matching lines.
```

Comment: an example: grep -oE ".{0,20}mysearchstring.{0,20}" myfile

Comment: you should change the answer to add -E option as shown by @Renaud (extended pattern option), or the proposed pattern for extending context wont work.

Comment: Not that necessary maybe but here's an example: 
`$ echo "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqMYSTRINGwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" > fileonelongline.txt 
&& grep -oE ".{0,20}MYSTRING.{0,20}" ./fileonelongline.txt
`  prints `qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqMYSTRINGwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww`

Comment: This works well; but notable downside is that when using, e.g., `oE ".{0,20}mysearchstring.{0,20}"`, you lose the highlighting of the inner "original" string against the context, because the whole thing becomes the search pattern.  Would love to find a way to keep some non-highlighted context around the search results, for much easier visual scanning and result interpretation.

Comment: Oh, here's a solution to the highlighting problem caused by using the `-oE ".{0,x}foo.{0,x}"` approach (where `x` is the number of characters of context) -- append ` | grep foo ` to the end.  Works for either ack or grep solutions. More solutions also here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163726/limit-grep-context-to-n-characters-on-line

Answer (score 57):

Pipe your results thru `cut`.  I'm also considering adding a `--cut` switch so you could say `--cut=80` and only get 80 columns.

Comment: What if the part that matches is not in the first 80 characters?

Comment: FWIW I appended `| cut=c1-120` to the grep, worked for me (though don't know how to cut around matched text)

Comment: ``| cut=c1-120`` didn't work for me, I needed to do ``| cut -c1-120``

Comment: I think @edib is accurate in syntax `| cut -c 1-100`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954102/1815624

Comment: @AndyLester: What about a `--no-wrap` option that uses `$COLUMNS`?

Comment: @naught101 You can submit it as an issue https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3/issues  Remember that ack also runs on Windows and I don't know that if they have `$COLUMNS`

Comment: Existing feature request: https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3/issues/234

Answer (score 28):

You could use less as a pager for ack and chop long lines: `ack --pager="less -S"`  This retains the long line but leaves it on one line instead of wrapping.  To see more of the line, scroll left/right in less with the arrow keys.

I have the following alias setup for ack to do this:

```
alias ick='ack -i --pager="less -R -S"'
```

Comment: Please note that you can put that `--pager` command in your ~/.ackrc file, if you always want to use it.

Comment: This sounds like the best solution by far to this problem that bugs me a lot. I wish I knew how to use `ack`.

Comment: @BrianPeterson `ack` is pretty much just like `grep`, only simpler in the most common cases

Answer (score 19):

#### `grep -oE ".{0,10}error.{0,10}" mylogfile.txt`

*In the unusual situation where you cannot use `-E`, use lowercase `-e` instead.*

Explanation:
[image: illustrative command explanation]

Comment: Do no use backslashes - `grep -oE ".{0,10}error.{0,10}" mylogfile.txt` - at least in Z zhell

Answer (score 16):

To get characters from 1 to 100.

```
cut -c 1-100
```

You might want to base the range off the current terminal, e.g.

```
cut -c 1-$(tput cols)
```

Answer (score 3):

I put the following into my `.bashrc`:

```
grepl() {
    $(which grep) --color=always $@ | less -RS
}
```

You can then use `grepl` on the command line with any arguments that are available for `grep`. Use the arrow keys to see the tail of longer lines. Use `q` to quit.

Explanation:

- `grepl() {`: Define a new function that will be available in every (new) bash console.
- `$(which grep)`: Get the full path of `grep`. (Ubuntu defines an alias for `grep` that is equivalent to `grep --color=auto`. We don't want that alias but the original `grep`.)
- `--color=always`: Colorize the output. (`--color=auto` from the alias won't work since `grep` detects that the output is put into a pipe and won't color it then.)
- `$@`: Put all arguments given to the `grepl` function here.
- `less`: Display the lines using `less`
- `-R`: Show colors
- `S`: Don't break long lines

Answer (score 2):

Taken from: http://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/08/18/truncate-long-matching-lines-of-grep-a-solution-that-preserves-color/

The suggested approach `".{0,10}<original pattern>.{0,10}"` is perfectly good except for that the highlighting color is often messed up. I've created a script with a similar output but the color is also preserved:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#   grepl PATTERN [FILE]

# how many characters around the searching keyword should be shown?
context_length=10

# What is the length of the control character for the color before and after the
# matching string?
# This is mostly determined by the environmental variable GREP_COLORS.
control_length_before=$(($(echo a | grep --color=always a | cut -d a -f '1' | wc -c)-1))
control_length_after=$(($(echo a | grep --color=always a | cut -d a -f '2' | wc -c)-1))

grep -E --color=always "$1" $2 |
grep --color=none -oE \
    ".{0,$(($control_length_before + $context_length))}$1.{0,$(($control_length_after + $context_length))}"
```

Assuming the script is saved as `grepl`, then `grepl pattern file_with_long_lines` should display the matching lines but with only 10 characters around the matching string.

Comment: Works, but outputs trailing junk for me, like this: ^\[\[?62;9;c. I haven't tried debugging because [@Jonah Braun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038776) satisfied me.

Answer (score 2):

[The Silver Searcher (ag)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) supports its natively via the `--width NUM` option. It will replace the rest of longer lines by `[...]`.

Example (truncate after 120 characters):

```
 $ ag --width 120 '@patternfly'
 ...
 1:{"version":3,"file":"react-icons.js","sources":["../../node_modules/@patternfly/ [...]
```

In ack3, a [similar feature is planned](https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3/issues/325) but currently not implemented.

Comment: but in `ag`, the width "begins" with first character, so this doesn't quite work when the string is in the middle of a very long line

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
function grep () {
  tput rmam;
  command grep "$@";
  tput smam;
}
```

In my .bash_profile, I [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399516/1483861) grep so that it automatically runs `tput rmam` before and `tput smam` after, which disabled wrapping and then re-enables it.

Comment: That is a nice alternative - except if the actual match is then out of screen...

Answer (score 0):

`ag` can also take the regex trick, if you prefer it:

```
ag --column -o ".{0,20}error.{0,20}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**`bgrep` if lines don't necessarily fit into memory**

`grep` [only works if the lines fit into memory](https://superuser.com/questions/1703029/is-there-a-limit-for-a-line-length-for-grep-command-to-process-correctly), but bgrep also works on huge lines that don't.

I keep coming back to this random repo from time to time: https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep Install:

```
curl -L 'https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/raw/master/bgrep.c' | gcc -O2 -x c -o $HOME/.local/bin/bgrep -
```

Use:

```
bgrep `printf %s saf | od -t x1 -An -v | tr -d '\n '` myfile.bin
```

Sample output:

```
myfile.bin: c80000003
\x02abc
myfile.bin: c80000007
dabc
```

I have tested it on files that don't fit into memory, and it worked just fine.

I've given further details at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-a-big-binary-file/758528#758528