# How to overwrite a bash command?

Tags: bash

So I basically am trying to overwrite my `ssh` command so I only have to type `ssh` and by default it would connect to my main server.  Then if I passed it an argument, say `username@server_port` it would then run the basic command.

```
# Fast SSH  (a working progress) TODO: make work without naming the function `fssh`
function fssh() {

    ALEX_SERVER_CONNECTION=$ALEX_SERVER_UNAME@$ALEX_SERVER_PORT

    # if the `ssh` argument is not set
    if [ -z "${1+xxx}" ]; then
        # echo "ALEX_SERVER_CONNECTION is not set at all";
        ssh $ALEX_SERVER_CONNECTION
    fi

    # if the `ssh` argument is set
    if [ -z "$1" ] && [ "${1+xxx}" = "xxx" ]; then
        ssh $1
    fi
}
```

**How do I get it to work without the `f` in front of the `ssh`?**

Comment: I was thinking if I included the path to where the `ssh` is defined, I could include something like `source /path/to/ssh` and it might work, but I can't find the right path to try.

Comment: Can you provide error message if any? Did you place your function in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @AlexCory could you clarify what is your goal as it is ambiguous and leading to totaling different answers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Solution

You need to specify the **absolute path to `ssh`** command in your function otherwise it will be recursive. For instance, instead of:

```bash
function ssh() { ssh $USER@localhost; } # WRONG!
```

You should write:

```bash
function ssh() { command ssh $USER@localhost; }
```

Use `command` built-in to get the `ssh` from the `PATH` (as suggested by @chepner):

> command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
>
> ```
>   Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the normal shell function
>   lookup. **Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH  are
>   executed**.
> ```

### Why not Alias?

Using a *function* is the correct pattern, read the [Aliases and Functions sections from the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html).

> **ALIASES**
>
> There  is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. **If
>   arguments are needed, a shell function should be used** (see FUNCTIONS
>   below).

### Diagnostic

When naming your custom function `ssh` do the following:

1. be sure to reload your shell configuration: `source ~/.bashrc`
2. check what is `ssh` with: `which ssh` or `type ssh`

#### `type` and `which`

Prior to declaring a custom function I got:

```bash
type ssh  # → ssh is /usr/bin/ssh
which ssh # → /usr/bin/ssh
```

After declaring `function ssh() { ssh my-vm; }`, I got:

```bash
which ssh # → ssh () { ssh my-vm; }
type ssh  # → ssh is a shell function
```

### Advices

Either use `sh` or `bash` syntax:

- `sh`: test is done with `[ … ]`, portable but not powerful ;
- `bash` test is done `[[ … ]]` and `function` keyword, less portable but dev-friendly.

Comment: In place of an absolute path to `ssh`, you can also use the `command` builtin, which retains the ability to do path lookup while avoiding a recursive call to the function. `function ssh() { command ssh $USER@localhost; }`

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get it to work without the f in front of the ssh?

Set an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ssh='fssh'
```

Comment: why should he need an alias? Function is fine

Comment: He already has a `fssh` function. Alias is for giving another name to OP's `fssh` function.

Comment: Yep, and as stated in first line he try to "overwrite my ssh", comment on 1st line of script indicate he don't want to name the function `fssh`

Comment: Naming the function is OP's choice, sure it can be renamed to `ssh` as well or just alias it.

Answer (score 0):

Say your script is called `fssh` and is executable, you just have to:

```
alias ssh='fssh'
```

in your `.bashrc`

Comment: A solution could be to copy/paste your code in a script `fssh`, get rid of `function` declaration, make it executable with `chmod +x fssh` and the alias will work.

Comment: Why an external script? If you leverage `alias` mechanism, you can also leverage `function`s so why bother with external script for a user-scope customization?

Comment: I don't see how is it bothering, I rather find it more handy to visualize your customization and toggle it.