# How to do a grep-like search on a very long line?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

grep is great at finding lines that match a pattern. But what if you have a file with a single extremely long line (say a 100MB file), and you want to find chunks within it that match a pattern?

For each match, you'd want to print the character offset, and the matched string, with extra characters on either side for context.

In Python, you could write something like this (would need boundary checks):

```
[(m.start(), s[m.start()-50:m.end()+50]) for m in re.finditer(regex, s)]
```

But is there some way to do the equivalent using standard linux command line tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each match, you'd want to print the offset, and the matched string, with extra characters on either side for context.

You can do that with awk like this:

```
awk '{
  i = 1
  while (match(substr($0, i), /regex/)) {
    off = i + RSTART - 1
    print off, substr($0, off > 50 ? off - 50 : 1, RLENGTH + 100)
    i = off + RLENGTH
  }
}' file
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is not memory efficient, as it loads the entire massive string in memory. A better solution we handle the string in chunks, but it is significantly more complex.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes. awk is not the right tool for that though

Answer (score 2):

[How to truncate long matching lines returned by grep or ack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034799/how-to-truncate-long-matching-lines-returned-by-grep-or-ack/63165087#63165087) gives a good one supposing the line fits into memory:

```
grep -Eo '.{0,15}needle.{0,15}' longlines.txt
```

If the lines don't necessarily into memory, then have a look at `bgrep`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-a-big-binary-file/758528#758528

```
bgrep `printf %s needle | od -t x1 -An -v | tr -d '\n '` myfile.bin
```